# Advanced mathematics in stringed instrument industry

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, applications, music-theory

This is a soft question. I play classical guitar and I find stringed instrument industry a very fascinating art. I know that, at least for classical guitar, this industry is still developing and exploring new techniques, so it is a very alive research field.

I know that it must involve at least some basic mathematics, but I was wondering if anyone has tried to apply deep mathematical tools and concepts in this field, for example from geometric analysis.

On the other hand I guess that these techniques could inspire very interesting mathematical questions.

What is the state of art of the interaction between maths and stringed instrument industry?

Comment: Here's a book which discusses the interplay between category theory and music: https://www.amazon.ca/Topos-Music-Geometric-Concepts-Performance/dp/3764357312

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Not convinced those kind of esoteric things are the most interesting :) I would recommend instead to think to this as an applied maths subject, with some practical goals.

Comment: @Onil90 What exactly is your goal?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Thanks for the reference. :)

Comment: @Narasimham I play classical guitar and I study math, so I am curious to know the links. Moreover I'm sure that there are deep math questions arising from trying to model the physical behaviour of a stringed instrument vibrating. I was wondering if there is a fruitful interaction between math and the stringed instrument industry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of what your question is. There are the 3 major *applied.maths/music* topics :

- Musical signal processing (automatic transcription, recognition).
- A.I. and machine learning (automatic improvisation, computer assisted composition)
- Physics & acoustic of musical instruments and sound synthesis.

The last one is special because the human voice is a musical instrument, and voice synthesis and analysis is a very active research field since more than 40 years.

All those subjects involve many mathematical tools : harmonic analysis (Fourier transform), differential equations & operator theory, convex optimization, probability and statistics, graph or group theory..

See [this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/files/papers/stanm119.pdf) for a good start on the physics of stringed instruments.

Comment: I am interested in the physics of musical instruments. Is there any reference book which deal rigorously with this topic from a mathematical viewpoint?

Comment: @Onil90 I wouldn't recommend a book, but there are a lot of resource on the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a look to that .pdf!

Comment: Nodes/antinodes of string vibration,, frequecy of notes,  Chaldini figures , Stradivarius etc.  Google it..           [StingedInstrum][1]                                                                                                                         [1]: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=physics%20of%20string%20instruments&espv=2&biw=1167&bih=577&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH1Y6Ox7rRAhUGTY8KHV_ECGgQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=EI_uId2op5aFkM%3A